# List comprehension que sea capaz de contar dentro de una lista cuantas listas tienen un valor mayor a 0

Tags: python

A partir de histograma se me genera un lista de listas con el siguiente aspecto,

```
[[9.]
 [3.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [2.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
```

Mi intención es contar cuantas listas interiores tienen un valor diferente de cero, en este caso 6. Eso como tal no hay problema, pero me gustaría hacerlo haciendo uso de las **list comprehension**.

Esto es lo que he probado,

```
histr_b = cv2.calcHist([crop_img],[0],None,[18],[2,20])
bb = 0
bb = [bb+1 for h in histr_b if h > 0]
```

El problema es que así lo único que consigo es poner un 1 en caso de que `h` sea mayor a 0. ¿Como se debería hacer? Obviamente ahora puedo hacer un `len(bb)` y saber cuantos son. Pero la gracia es que la línea de código anterior sea capaz de hacer ese conteo.

¡Un saludo y salud para todos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de una lista por compresión usa mejor `sum` y una expresión generadora, si quieres solo contar crear una lista es una pérdida de recursos:

```
sum(sublista[0] > 0 for sublista in lista)
```

Aunque  **lo que tienes es un array de Numpy, no una lista**, en tal caso para éste ejemplo concreto, deberías hacer:

```
sum(1 for h in histr_b if h[0] > 0)
```

o

```
sum(histr_b[:, 0] > 0)
```

pero mejor aprovecha NumPy:

```
np.count_nonzero(histr_b > 0)
```

que **debería ser la opción preferida por eficiencia** (*ver al final de la respuesta). También se podría usar `numpy.sum`:

```
np.sum(histr_b > 0)
```

Si se tienen más de una columna (que no es el caso) se debe hacer un slicing previo o contará los mayores de 0 en todas:

```
np.count_nonzero(histr_b[:, 0] > 0)
np.sum(histr_b[:, 0] > 0)
```

o usar el argumento `axis` con valor 0, lo que nos contará los mayores de cero por columna:

```
np.count_nonzero(histr_b > 0, axis=0)
np.sum(histr_b > 0, axis=0)
```

la salida es otro array con un entero por cada columna cuyo valor es la cantidad de números mayores de 0 en esa columna.

---

*Si hacemos una pequeña comparación de tiempos de ejecución:

> ```
> %timeit sum(1 for h in histr_b if h[0] > 0)
> 23.3 µs ± 222 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>
> %timeit sum(histr_b[:, 0] > 0)
> 37.6 µs ± 505 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>
> %timeit np.count_nonzero(histr_b > 0)
> 4.08 µs ± 33.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>
> %timeit np.sum(histr_b > 0)
> 12.4 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
> ```

El claro ganador es `numpy.count_nonzero`.